# Amazon SageMaker how to predict new data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, aws-code-deploy

I built the model in Amazon SageMaker, the code is attached below.
Now I would like to be able to upload new data to s3 and get predictions based on this model without having to recalculate it every time.

```
sess = sagemaker.Session()
bucket = "innogy-bda-germany-dev-landing-dc3-retailpl"
prefix = "sagemaker/xgboost-upsell"
role = get_execution_role()
container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", boto3.Session().region_name, "latest")
display(container)

train_path = 's3://innogy-bda-germany-dev-landing-dc3-retailpl/UPSELL/LIST/train.csv'
test_path = 's3://innogy-bda-germany-dev-landing-dc3-retailpl/UPSELL/LIST/validation.csv'
s3_input_train = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data=train_path, content_type='csv')
s3_input_test = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data=test_path, content_type='csv')

sess = sagemaker.Session()

xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container,
    role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.4xlarge",
    output_path="s3://innogy-bda-germany-dev-landing-dc3-retailpl/UPSELL/LIST/output",
    sagemaker_session=sess,
)
xgb.set_hyperparameters(
    alpha= 1.340343927865692,
    colsample_bytree= 0.525162855476281,
    eta= 0.06451533130134757,
    gamma= 0.9683995477068462,
    max_depth= 10,
    min_child_weight= 3.851108988963441,
    num_round= 987,
    subsample= 0.8725573749114485,
    silent=0,
    objective="binary:logistic",
    early_stopping_rounds=50,
)

xgb.fit({"train": s3_input_train, "validation": s3_input_validation})
```

I am asking for a code example, how to extract this model from s3 to a new notebook now and use it to predict new data.

Additionally, I wonder why You don't throw away the target variable while using the built-in xgboost model in sagemaker since when making a prediction on a new set, I will not know the target.

```
train_data, validation_data, test_data = np.split(df_smote.sample(frac=1, random_state=1729),[int(0.7 * len(df_smote)), int(0.9 * len(df_smote))],)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow the steps outlined here to deploy your model to an EC2 instance, so you can do batch or on-demand predictions.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-model-deployment.html